# couldn't connect in kafka tool because of timeout

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

i have kafka tool 2.0.7 and i want to connect into my local.

[image]

but when i want to connect it, it always turn like this

`error connecting to the cluster. Timeout connecting to broker(s), bootstrap.servers= localhost:9092`

and because of that reason, i went to `tools` and set the zookeeper Timeout but always turn

`general settings: Please enter valid value for 'zookeeper timeout'`.

where my wrong at?

Comment: It's asking for the Zookeeper port. You gave it the broker port. And based on your other question, Zookeeper isn't running, meaning Kafka wouldn't either

Comment: so basically it's because kafka not run in my system? and i have to install kafka? i thought when my laptop already have kafka tool, it means that i already have kafka (sorry im still new in apache-kafka)

Comment: I don't know why your laptop would already have Kafka Tool installed. If it's a company computer, they'd be the ones installing things... Apache Kafka, itself, has no GUI tools that come with it and the Kafka Tool you're using requires a running Kafka cluster and an accessible Zookeeper endpoint (which most, public, Kafka providers do not provide)